# CakePHP Resque composer install error

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0, resque

I have installed CakePHP via Composer with the following command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app_name
```

as mentioned in [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html).

I need the [kamisama/cake-resque](https://packagist.org/packages/kamisama/cake-resque) plugin, but when i use `composer require kamisama/cake-resque`, I am getting the following errors

```
Using version ^4.1 for kamisama/cake-resque
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump
Script Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump      
handling the post-autoload-dump event terminated with an exception

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                          
Unable to get primary namespace for package kamisama/cake-resque.                                                                           
Ensure you have added proper 'autoload' section to your plugin's    
config as stated in README on https://github.com/cakephp/plugin-installer  


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Looks like that plugin is for Cake 2, but you're using Cake 3?

Comment: Yes, I am using cake 3.*